# Cannot run PowerShell Scripts from Cmd.exe that has an "&" in it to call another powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, parallel-processing

I have a powershell script file called test.ps1 written as follows:

in the ps1 file, contents are:

```
& 'C:\Invoke-Parallel.ps1'

$Sciptblock = {.....}

Invoke-Parallel -scriptblock $Scriptblock -inputobject $(get-content "C:\info.txt") -runspaceTimeout 300 -throttle 30 -NoCloseonTimeOut -quiet
```

I have a problem running this in windows command prompt because '&' is not invoking the script that I am using (Invoke-Parallel.ps1) for the new script that I created.

I could get this to work when the script runs inside Powershell window or even in Powershell ISE but not in the command line.

Please let me know what command line I need to use to run this successfully or it is not possible to do this in windows commandline. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Error I got when I ran this:

> The term 'Invoke-Parallel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At C:\test.ps1:9 char:16 + Invoke-Parallel <<<< 
>   -scriptblock $Scriptblock -inputobject $(get-content "C:\info.txt") -runspaceTimeout 300 -throttle 30 -NoCloseonTimeOut -quiet
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Parallel:String) [], Com    mandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Dont you want to `Import-Module C:\Invoke-Parallel.ps1`?

Comment: If I use Import-module, won't I have to do more than just convert ps1 extension to psm file?

Comment: no. you can even import a ps1 afaik

Comment: The motivation to have this work in Windows Command prompt is so that I can use Windows Task Scheduler to run the powershell script at regular time of the day.

Comment: jisaak, I tried but it says: Import-Module : The specified module 'invoke-parallel.ps1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory. At line:1 char:14
+ import-module <<<<  invoke-parallel.ps1
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (invoke-parallel.ps1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: did you specifiy the full path? e. g. `Import-Module "C:\Invoke-Parallel.ps1"` ? Ensure the path exisits

Comment: If Invoke-Parallel.ps1 has an Invoke-Parallel function in it, you need to dot-source the file rather than invoke (&) it.

Comment: Mike, How do I dot-source a ps1 file within a ps1 file itself? I tried dot-sourcing, that is dot followed by a space and full path of the ps1 file. Probably my syntax is not right. It won't work and so I had to use invoke (&) in the ps1 file.

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments above I think your looking to make a batch file
that you then call via task scheduler that then launches your PowerShell script

Example Batch file to launch a script:
`@echo off
powershell -command "start-process cmd -argumentlist /C,powershell,'-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned',%~dp0\<your script name>.ps1 -verb RunAs -WindowStyle Hidden"`
How this works and what it does:
echo off is just so you don't see the command prompt code when it is launched
next starts a Windows Command Prompt session which launches PowerShell (/C just indicates to cmd that after its done to terminate and exit its session)
set excutionpolicy is there in case this is on machine where remotesigned hasn't been done and because its only for this instance it will revert back to default after
-verb RunAs is run in admin mode
windowstyle hidden is so that the whole thing happens in the background remove this if this is not wanted
%~dp0 is code for cmd to use its own location for the path so if you use this make sure the batch file is always in the same folder as your script

I should add to make a batch file create a txt file write in the code and save as and change the extension to bat instead of txt then use Task Scheduler to launch the batch file to accomplish your goal